# How to give a swagger parameter default value?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, swagger, swagger-ui

I want somes params on swagger have its own default value. Is there anyway to give a default value ?
like this 
[this note has to be filled automatically with "stackoverflow"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbTSq.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to annotate your `note` parameter with `defaultValue="stackoverflow"`.

You method signature  should look like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> yourMethod(@ApiParam(value = "Default value for note", required = true, defaultValue = "stackoverflow") @Valid @RequestParam final String note) { }
```

Comment: what if i store some param in a class let's say SomeParams and i call it like this (at)Valid (at)ModelAttribute SomeParams param, how can i add default value to this ?