# Swagger UI Pageable object sort variable is defaulted to "string"

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

In my spring boot app, in the rest endpoint I am accepting a pageable object as a parameter. But in the Swagger UI the default value for the sort variable is shown as ["string"]. Is there a way to make it [] or ["id"] so it won't throw an exception.

Default Pageable object in the swagger UI

```
{
 "page": 0,
 "size": 1,
 "sort": [
   "string"
 ]
}
```

Endpoint

```
public ResponseListDTO<?> getAllNames(Pageable pageable) {..}
```

Comment: The annotations may have changed, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503977/6650475) should help.